# Social Credit System in a Non-modern-technology Type World

Tags: technology, dystopia, governance

Dystopian fiction is fun, but it often relies on futuristic/modern technology - such as cameras watching your every move - and various other devices that can track whatever you do. In a world where technology is in more of an early stage, such as when those big clunky computers and TV's were first being used, how would the big evil government keep track of its citizens in order to properly reward them for "good" behaviour?

For a bit of background: this takes place in a single, massive city ruled over by what is, essentially, a dictatorship. They have electricity and magic, which doesn't matter since it's really just chemical reactions on steroids, and can't be used in a wizardly fashion. Technology is around the 1950s-70s range in the early stages of computer tech, with a few key differences: they have what amount to tablets, which are very simple compared to what we have and are used solely for communication via what would be described at its simplest as a radio network. Computers are generally used for the same; to store information and send it between units in a closed-network. Cameras exist, but are early-stage and haven't yet been distributed across the city for surveillance, partly because it would be extremely expensive to do so, and they're too bulky to hide away from opportunists. In the same vein, TVs are in most mid-upper class homes, but unfortunately can't be bugged to spy on the inhabitants.

With few ways to keep track of the populace, they would probably be forced to resort to non-technological methods like paperwork and various sign-in procedures in order to monitor the population, which would be hell to keep track of without the assistance of AI and algorithms. Then there's the problem of having the populace be aware of their social "score" in order to keep them focused on climbing up, which possibly can't be automated since the calculation capabilities of the computers are limited.

**In a society like this, how could you apply a social credit system to the populace?**

(Ps: if anyone can help me make this clearer - as my spaghetti-brain will have inevitably glossed over important details or gotten things wrong - I'd appreciate it, thanks)

Comment: china actually tried this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Credit_System the prelude was needing a way to keep all branches of government in constant contact

Comment: In the city I grew up is a four-story customized building occupying an entire city block which was one average-sized bank's late-1960s computer center. On the next block was a ten-story office building for all the clerks that did the data input and searches and output, and all the phone trunks they required and the mail rooms and printing rooms and tape vaults, etc. Moving and storing and searching data before 1995-or-so was massively expensive. The only thing more expensive was trying to do it all on paper. You can *collect* data, but distributing and *using* it well is another story.

Comment: Downvoted. For  a change waiting for a good mnagment system, as intencions so as results.

Comment: @AlexP Huh, kinda wonder why that didn't come up in the list of questions already asked that I looked through all the way to the very bottom :/ Yes, that is helpful, thanks!

Comment: @MolbOrg Thanks, buddy. Nice to know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was actually implemented in our history in various countries around the same technological level, i.e. starting in the 1950s through 1970s.

Let's take Czechoslovakia for example - everyone (adult, employed - and there was no unemployment) had a dossier ([Kádrový posudek/posudok](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1drov%C3%BD_posudek)), maintained by a special department of the employing institution (these were centralized and huge, so the overhead was not too big), keeping track of social and political activity of the person. One could advance his/her/their score by being a good employee, by being politically active, by being socially active, by entering the Communist Party; or in the negative direction e.g. by causing family problems (beating your wife...), alcoholism, rude behaviour, or outright destroy it by anti-communist political activity.

This very much influenced things like promotions, access to organized vacation, ability to travel abroad, getting an apartment etc.

Edit: On the technology, there was quite change from the 1950s to the 1970s, but generally, there were no personal tablets, but there were fixed line phones, mainly used for personal communications, computers were big and clunky, used mostly for number crunching but later more and more for data processing, mostly within closed networks (the mainframe paradigm); TVs were initially found only in upper-mid income houses but later on became more accessible, but they were strictly one way only; electricity was ubiquitous; cameras existed but were too expensive to waste on CCTV surveillance of public places (mostly for military establishment, industrial processes or other important places).

Answer (score 2):

I am going to quote my own [answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stasi) to another question, because it fits both the setting and the time period:

A good reference could be what [Stasi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stasi) did in DDR, in particular with [Zersetzung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zersetzung).

> the methods of overt persecution that had been employed up to that time, such as arrest and torture, were too crude and obvious. It was realised that psychological harassment was far less likely to be recognised for what it was, so its victims, and their supporters, were less likely to be provoked into active resistance

Infiltrate society with a capillary network of mutually unknown informants, so that nobody can say who is a safe contact.

Moreover avoid as much as possible to embody a well defined enemy, which is known to boost morale and sense of group.

Answer (score 2):

### Behaviour in...

The primary difficulty in a system like this is noticing undesirable behaviour. The term "social credit" implies that people know how well they're doing, and know how to do better.

**Good:**

- Attending the "right" events and saying the "right" things is an easy way to accrue Good.
- Informing on others is a fast track to bonus Good points.
- Staying in a predictable pattern is Good.
- Logging your own movements (verified by checkpoints) is Good.
- Government-sponsored employment is Good.
- Suggestions for improving the system are Good.
- Praise for the system is Good.

**Bad:**

- Time spent away from checkpoints is Bad. (By implication, if not outright.)
- Buying the wrong products is Bad.
- Undocumented cash/payments are Bad.
- Associating with undesirables is Bad.
- Being in the vicinity of undesirables is Bad.
- Crime is Bad (unless authority approves it).
- Acknowledging the existence of this system is Bad.

To destabilise matters, have your dictator declare that the colour blue is Bad, including looking up at the sky.

Breathing is, on average, Bad - a city will have their scores adjusted to keep a zero-mean every week, so you have to keep being Good. This implicitly means that higher compliance raises the standard.

### ... Feedback out.

Borrowing from existing implementations and *Black Mirror*, being Bad comes with penalties to every controllable aspect of life.

- Employers don't want to work with Bad people.
- Banks will charge more interest on a Bad loan.
- Restaurants and services can refuse to serve you.
- Forget about any kind of prestige, you'll have to work twice as hard just to eat.
- Leaving is out of the question, since the countryside has few checkpoints and you'll end up being imprisoned for being Bad even if you do make it to another city.

On the other hand, being Good makes everything better. Yes, everyone nearby is suspicious of you (informer!) and you have to watch your every action to make it fit the mould; but as long as you do, you can:

- Appear on TV (State-owned)
- Move easily
- Access the most expensive and exclusive areas, to rub shoulders with the Good (and not lose your rating)
- Instant/fast-tracked promotion in some fields

### Everyone knows.

A neighbourhood bulletin is given out weekly, showing who near here is Good or Bad, as well as what areas are doing well. Neighbours will press the Bad to conform, and try to show off themselves. Especially Good sorts will move away to more "fitting" areas.

---

**Assumptions:**

- Visible nametagging (ID-numbers) for all official functions, strict enforcement of nametag-visibility.
- Reasonable spy network to capture >1% of public conversations.
- Checkpoints are able to communicate a list of who passed a checkpoint back to the Central Registry by radio-tablet.
- This dystopia has enough staff to manage such a simplified system.

Of course, the fun of the story can come in with someone who knows how to hack/game this system.

Comment: The colour blue is an Abomination Unto Nuggan!  X-D  
 https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Nuggan

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! The possibility of checkpoints didn't occur to me; using the tablets to communicate lists of people who pass through would work quite well

Answer (score 1):

**Have the populace do it for you**

Population control is difficult, unless you can let the populace do things for you. This can be out of fear, respect, culture or mixes of those, but in the end the populace will assist. Extreme examples can be found easily. For example, the deportation of Jews was aided by the populace in many countries. Some out of fear, some simply because they were the rules, or they hated the Jews because of propaganda or misguided thoughts, some out of respect (of power) for the Germans. Many knew or could guess that there wasn't something nice waiting for the Jews, yet they did it anyway. Sometimes even without expecting benefits for themselves.

To achieve this you can do several things at once. Make it the rules. Make sure the populace feels negative when social score reduces and positive when it increases. Make people complicit if they don't act against (social) rule breakers. If someone is jaywalking and you don't report them, you'll be punished as if you're the jaywalker or even worse for not reporting it. These things will help you severely reduce the amount of people needed for control. People will be clamouring over each other to report their neighbours for wife abuse (if illegal), or not cleaning their porch, or going to anti-establishment meetings. The main point is that they will help you control themselves.

The credit can be tallied at any officer with a tablet. The social credit can be directly linked to what you're allowed to buy or do, but it can also be the money itself. The mechanisms of positive and negative reinforcement are up to you.